# Why trying to run Vue.js it does not work properly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i can't start my Vue.js application

the error is:

```
   C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-front>npm run dev

> crm-front@1.0.0 dev C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-front
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
   throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-front\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
?[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)?[39m
?[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)?[39m
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-front\node_modules\?[4mwebpack-dev-server?[24m\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:56:1)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)?[39m {
 code: ?[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'?[39m,
 requireStack: [
   ?[32m'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\crm-front\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'?[39m
 ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! crm-front@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the crm-front@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amedeo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-23T12_26_07_551Z-debug.log
```

I tried to downgrade to version 2.9.1 as recommended on other forums but it doesn't work anyway

Can you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to run vue.js with `npm run serve` instead of `npm run dev`

Comment: i try but:
C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-front>npm run serve
npm ERR! missing script: serve

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amedeo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-23T18_31_16_204Z-debug.log